# How to run a java application and uses its output to run maven artifacts?

Tags: java, maven

I need to run a java application, if its output is "Passed" then I will run `mvn site` command. I have gone through several forums and got to know this can be done using pre-site goal but how will i validate the "Passed" state. The Java Application is a command that is used to invoke a Python script. If it runs successfully then output is passed. If i run from Hudson I can put the command in Pre-Build Step. But How will I validate if the output is passed or failed. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Jenkins's 'Execute Shell' help:

> the build is considered a failure if any of the commands exits with a
>   non-zero exit code.

So you should make the Java application return 0 if passed, and something else otherwise. You can use `System.exit(0)` for that.

If you have no control over the java application, you can use `tail -1 | grep Passed` to see if the command had "Passed" in its final line.

Comment: Is there any method by which if java application returns "Passed"..it updates pom.xml.

Comment: It's not clear, really, what you're trying to do. If you want to block the `site` phase if the java command fails, run the java command with the exec plugin, bound to `pre-site`. That should prevent `site` if the command returns non-success.

Comment: In term of pom what will be non-success in pre-site phase. I am new to maven please bear with me..

Comment: By convention, a program returns 0 on success, or any other code on failure.

Comment: I think the best solution is to bundle `mvn exec:java` and `mvn site` in a batch file and then use it from hudson. Will it be feasible?

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary, and a batch file isn't cross-platform. What's wrong with running just `mvn site`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10589/discussion-between-amit-shakya-and-artbristol)